# C++ Menu. Unlimited loop in menu

Tags: c++

Hey can anyone see what wrong with my menu in the while loop it keeps printing out dixie if i press 1 in an unlimited loop.  I have a while loop around the menu so that the menu is always there for the user to go back through choices.
here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int choice;
    bool menu = true;
    cout <<"========Welcome to the database menu========\n";

    cout << "Press 1 to insert a new record at a particular position\n"
            "Press 2 to delete a record from a particular position\n"
            "Press 3 to search the database  and print results\n"
            "Press 5 to find the average experience points of players at a particular level\n"
            "Press 6 to find and remove all duplicate entries\n"
            "Press 0 to quit\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n";

    cout << "Choice: ";
    cin >> choice;
    //*****************************************************************************
    // Switch menu to display the menu.
    //*****************************************************************************
    while(menu)
    {
        switch (choice)
        {
            case 1:
                cout << "dixie";
                break;
            case 2:
                cout << "bexie";
                break;
            default:
                cout<< "That is not a choice!!!\n";
        }
    }    
    getchar();
    getchar();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It says `while (menu)` and that means it'll keep doing that until you set menu to `false`.

Also, I think you want to add the `cin >> choice` in the loop, or it'll just repeat the selection again and again.

Answer (score 2):

There is no code that can change either `menu` or `choice` inside your `while` loop. So once it gets going, it will never stop.

Comment: so how would i stop it from loopin once a case is chosen but still show the menu options?

Comment: The problem is that your loop is in the wrong place. Looping until the user select `0` is fine, but you have to handle `0` in your `switch` statement. See my answer for possible solutions where the `while` loop should go.

Answer (score 0):

I would suppose the while loop should include printing the menu options and having the user select an option like so:

```
while (menu)
{
    cout <<"========Welcome to the database menu========\n";
    cout << "Press 1 to insert a new record at a particular position\n"
            "Press 2 to delete a record from a particular position\n"
            "Press 3 to search the database  and print results\n"
            "Press 5 to find the average experience points of players at a particular level\n"
            "Press 6 to find and remove all duplicate entries\n"
            "Press 0 to quit\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n";

    cout<< "Choice: ";
    cin>> choice;

    switch (choice)
    {
        case 1:
            cout << "dixie";
            break;
        case 2:
            cout << "bexie";
            break;
        default:
            cout<< "That is not a choice!!!\n";
    }
}
```

Another possibility would be to start the while loop just before the `cout << "Choice: "` line.

Answer (score 0):

`menu` variable is always `true` inside the loop. It's the same as `while(true)` at the moment.